# How make slideshow for images and video with SVG?

Tags: svg, jquery-svg

I have two images(png) and two video (mp4).
Need to make slideshow in next sequence:

- play video #1;
- show image and show some text with fade effect on bottom of image;
- show another image with some movement and zoom to center effect;
- play video #2;

Need to use SVG only. I mean just run example.svg and it should play slideshow above.

```
<svg width='100%' height='100%' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'>
    <foreignObject id='v1' width="640" height="420">
        <iframe xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" width="640" height="420" src="video1.ogg" frameborder="0"/>
    </foreignObject>
    <image width="640" height="1136" xlink:href="1.jpg">
        <animate id='a1' attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" begin='v1.end' from="1" to="0" dur="5s" repeatCount="1" />
   </image>
</svg>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does "SVG only" mean? Can you use `<foreignObject>` with HTML5 `<video>` element? Can you use JavaScript? If not, it's not possible in my eyes.

Comment: I mean that as result I should run just .svg file (without html or javascript)

Comment: In SVG 1.2 everything you want would be possible, but what viewers are you targeting? Do they support SVG Tiny 1.2? (I'm not aware of any such viewer, so if anyone can point me to one, that would be interesting.) The relevant information can be found [in the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/multimedia.html#VideoElement).

Comment: Opera supports SVG 1.2 Tiny.

Comment: need to support last versions of browsers, android 3.0 and later, iOS 6.0

Comment: In that case you can't do it with the restrictions you've specified.

Comment: @RobertLongson: So then the fact that Opera does not show the video of the [example in the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/examples/noonoo.svg) is due to an unsopported video format?

Comment: Indeed. Try an ogg theora video, that should work. e.g. http://download.blender.org/peach/trailer/trailer_400p.ogg

Comment: I updated code in my question. I added video with foreignObject but can't make sequence between video and image animation. v1.end or v1.ended() doesn't work.